# Remove html tag and string in between in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm pretty new with regular expression. Basically, I would like to use regular expression to remove `<sup> ... </sup>` from the string using regular expression.

Input:

```
<b>something here</b><sup>1</sup><sup>,3</sup>, another here<sup>1</sup>
```

Output:

```
<b>something here</b>, another here
```

Is that a short way and description on how to do it?

**note** This question might be duplicated. I tried but couldn't find solution.

Comment: Regex is not the way to deal with html, use an html parser. html isn't a simple string, it's structured data. The most easy to use is beautifulsoup, but it's only a wrapper for more efficient libraries you can use too.

Comment: I have list of short string like above. I guess using regular expression will work without using html parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard part is knowing how to do a minimal rather than maximal match of the stuff between the tags.  This works.

```
import re
s0 = "<b>something here</b><sup>1</sup><sup>,3</sup>, another here<sup>1</sup>"
prog = re.compile('<sup>.*?</sup>')
s1 = re.sub(prog, '', s0)
print(s1)
# <b>something here</b>, another here
```

Comment: Beaten by Ryan with same answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import re
s = "<b>something here</b><sup>1</sup><sup>,3</sup>, another here<sup>1</sup>"

s2 = re.sub(r'<sup>(.*?)</sup>',"", s)

print s2
# Prints: <b>something here</b>, another here
```

Remember to use `(.*?)`, as `(.*)` is what they call a greedy quantifier and you would obtain a different result:

```
s2 = re.sub(r'<sup>(.*)</sup>',"", s)

print s2
# Prints: <b>something here</b>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, this is exactly what I'm looking for.